# Is it safe to store coordinates on NFC tags always in one CRS and rely on conversion for others

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

I'm involved in NFC (Near Field Communication) standardization of a record structure for geographic point locations. That will allow to put coordinates on NFC memory tags which can be read with a smartphone or to exchange between phones and the like.

A first proposal made was to always include the coordinate tuple (2D or 3D) and the CRS, so a coordinate tuple for a specific CRS could be stored. To this, an alternative opinion claimed that the CRS could set implicitly (for example WGS-84) and coordinates for any other CRS be computed, of course only for the same dimensions.

It may be worth to note that a compact encoding format is important because NFC tags, especially the cheaper ones, do not provide a lot of memory. So any byte less is good if functionality isn't reduced (one envisioned use case is that NFC tags could be affixed to landmarks and allow the location be read electronically - this was thought to sometimes require other CRS than WGS-84).

So the question is, if a coordinate tuple is given in one CRS is it safe to assume that it can be converted to any other CRS of practical relevance?

To make this more open-ended, would there be any drawbacks if a data format for geographical coordinates is fixed to only one CRS and requires conversion to and from other CRSs if needed.

And as further explanation, the intention is not to derive a format for a specific application but for general use by anyone who wants to store or read a location from an NFC tag/card or share with another smartphone when touched (like to show the location on a map application). Similar to what RFC 5870 (Geo URI) provides but more compact.

Comment: Welcome to our site! Some searches should quickly indicate the answer is yes.  Keywords to use include [EPSG](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=EPSG), [tag:projection], and [tag:coordinate-system]. Consider editing your question to be a little more open-ended: given your requirement to minimize the storage of each coordinate, why not ask this community for suggestions? WGS84 latitude and longitude is not the only viable candidate. It would help for you to stipulate your data quality requirements, including accuracy and precision thresholds.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried to rephrase and provide more context, hope that works out better. Though I'm struggling a bit in how to best express the intention, my expertise is in NFC and not GIS. For most people outside a GIS community location means GPS and for many use cases that will be appropriate. But I meanwhile learned that there exists a wealth of CRSs which may all have there specific advantages, so would a format that is absolutely bound to one CRS eventually serve the needs of a GIS community?